# What is the hardware stack depth in TM4C123GH6PM?

Tags: stack, arm, microcontroller, forth

I am trying to implement a Forth system for [Tiva-C LaunchPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiva-C_LaunchPad). I am wondering about:

- What is the depth of the implemented hardware stack for instructions push and pop (I want to know if I can use it for PSP in Forth or not)?
- Any recommendations about the thread model to use with this chip?

Comment: How much RAM have you got below where SP is pointing? The answer is "that deep".

Comment: so. how can they implement 2 stacks: MSP and PSP?
or that is a software side?

Comment: In PIC they say it explicitly 8 cells deep hardware.

Comment: How can one implement two variables `int *a` and `int *b`? :P Of course, the other way to look at it would be that the _hardware_ stack depth is non-existent, because the stacks are in RAM.

Comment: I think I am confusing some concepts here.
I will look them up then rethink about it.

Comment: To be fair, if you're only familiar with the baseline/midrange PIC architectures, it may not be apparent that they're right down the "wacky embedded madness" end of the spectrum. In contrast, one of the points of the ARM M-profile architectures is that they bring the familiar programmer's model of the bigger general-purpose CPUs to the lower-end microcontroller space; it's definitely quite a contrast to most of the traditional 8-bit stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments:

There is no hardware stack in your terms. The Cortex-M4 has two stacks (Main Stack and Process Stack) that are both located in the RAM at different addresses and are selected by software. The selection depends on the **CONTROL** register.

Please refer to **2.1.2 Stacks** in *[Cortex-M4 Devices, Generic User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/DUI0553A_cortex_m4_dgug.pdf)*

With this given, it's apparent that the stacks could overflow.

Detailed discussion on stack and heap sizing: *[Defining the heap and stack size for an ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4013)*